# okta does not validate issuer, coming from sp

Tags: saml-2.0, okta, idp, passport-saml

I'm using okta as IDP for saml2 authentification, howver its works well, but I noticed that that octa does not check issuer , im confused about that, he shouldnt accept a request from any source provider, otherwise that will be a big issue

Comment: What do you mean "okta does not check issuer"? Okta is IdP, it's SP who needs to validate an assertion issued by IdP (Okta)

Comment: by another way, how IDP knows which SP send request to him? is it have unique entryPoint for each sp?

Comment: Okta does not care `who` sent the request. It will always respond to the request, but it's sent only to ACS URL configured for the app. So even you are are trying to be a malicious actor, the assertion is sent to the real ACS URL which was setup for the application, and not to a random URL